# Full Calender + Right Click is not working on the cell when events are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, contextmenu

I am using Full Calender JQuery Plugin for displaying my user's daily activity. I have added one drop-down menu when user right click on any cell. But I have an issue with that when we add an event on any cell. When we add an event on any cell then it will create a  on the whole row, So I am not able to add open drop-down menu on whole row.

It's displayed on the attached image. On red portion i may not able to open drop-down on right click.

[image]

**Code**

```
$(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasmenu",
    autoFocus: true,
    preventContextMenuForPopup: true,
    preventSelect: true,
    taphold: true,
    menu: [{
        title: "Block Date",
        cmd: "block",
        uiIcon: ""
    }],
    // Handle menu selection to implement a fake-clipboard
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // Block Date Code
    },
    // Implement the beforeOpen callback to dynamically change the entries
    beforeOpen: function (event, ui) {
        // Optionally return false, to prevent opening the menu now
    }
});

$('#my-calendar').fullCalendar({
    buttonText: {
        today:    'Today',
        month:    'Month',
        week:     'Week',
        day:      'Day',
        list:     'List'    
    },
    header: {
        left: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
        center: 'prev, title, next',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        // Code for display popup for event
    },
    dayRender: function (day, cell) {
        // Code for add hasmenu class for open context menu on right click
    },
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2017-07-01',
            color: '#000'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-07-07',
            end: '2017-07-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2017-07-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2017-07-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2017-07-11',
            end: '2017-07-13'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2017-07-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2017-07-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2017-07-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2017-07-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2017-07-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2017-07-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2017-07-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2017-07-28'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Probably the cells are wider than visually noticible. You can use the inspector to find what element is causing the 'overlay' which makes you unable to click the element behind it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But it's a default functionality of fullcalendar that when events are created in any date, it creates a whole <tbody> in that row, that creates overlay.

Comment: @Rav'sPatel paste your right click function also so we can check whats wrong with it.!

Comment: We have add "hasmenu" class to all the cell. It will open context menu.